# showing notifications using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

I use the flutter local notifications plugin but I don't know how to schedule notifications using
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule. noted that I can't use flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime because it's deprecated

Comment: If you just need to know how to use flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zone Schedule you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415592/flutter-scheduled-notification-datetime/64474953#64474953

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this :

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
0, 'Title', 'Body', time, platformChannel,
payload: 'New payload');
```

You can use this :

```
var dateTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
    DateTime.now().day, 18, 2, 0);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  0,
  'scheduled title',
  'scheduled body',
  tz.TZDateTime.from(dateTime, tz.local),
  platformChannel,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
);
```

I didn't test it, but this should repeat every day at 18:02.
Remember to add this package:

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
```